# Outlook Rule - How to add own email address as a TO recipient based on a bcc address?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access, exchange-2013

I am struggling to setup something like this as outlook rule (or any other means to accomplish this is most welcomed).

**Scenario :** Users would like to save emails to CRM while travelling. For this, CRM excepts emails such that the users' email id in TO and BCC to be a CRM account address.

**Issue :** Users are happy to bcc a crm email account but they would like to automate adding themselves in TO part.

After toiling with rules, I tried setting up a middle-man account, such that the users will copy that address and that account can trigger rules that would add the user in TO of the email  but no success either.

Wondering how can I alter the email such that the user's  address get added to it while bccing some other address.

(Cannot go down macros route since this is intended for users on travel using webmail)

Many thanks.

Comment: This can be configured inside the exchange server to always put the from in the to as well, regardless if the user wants this or not. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Thanks LPChip. This will work but only if we are able to put in a condition such that exchange does this only for emails which has bcc address as the crm email id. Is this possible ?  (the users would not be happy for every email to be sent back to them).